# SVG round corners with m0 0

Tags: svg

Please consider the following SVG:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=100 height=100 viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <!-- path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="10" stroke="black" d="M256 256 5 5 V507"/ -->
        <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="10" stroke="black" d="M256 256 5 5m0 0V507"/>
    </svg>
```

I want the top left corner to be rounded, hence, I am using `stroke-linecap="round"`. I would have expected the remarked path statement to work, but it yields a sharp corner. I did have to move the pointer relative by `m0 0` before drawing the vertical line `V507` to get the desired result. I don't understand why a relative `m0 0` movement makes sense. Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: m/M creates a new path segment?

Comment: `stroke-linecap` describes the form of line _ends_, `stroke-linejoin` the form of line _corners_.

Comment: that was my missing 'link', @ccprog! Wasn't documented in my beginner's guide [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_stroking.asp) But of course at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linejoin)